# Unexpected regex matching In R

Tags: regex, r

I've come across some unexpected behavior (at least to me) when trying to subset a data frame using `grepl`. Here's some example to illustrate the issue:

```
> myVec <- c("ISB*", "ISNB*")
> myDF <- data.frame(Source = rep(myVec, 5, 2), Value = 1:10)
> print(myDF)
   Source Value
1    ISB*     1
2   ISNB*     2
3    ISB*     3
4   ISNB*     4
5    ISB*     5
6   ISNB*     6
7    ISB*     7
8   ISNB*     8
9    ISB*     9
10  ISNB*    10
> myDF.b <- myDF[grepl("ISB*", myDF$Source), ]
> print(myDF.b)
   Source Value
1    ISB*     1
2   ISNB*     2
3    ISB*     3
4   ISNB*     4
5    ISB*     5
6   ISNB*     6
7    ISB*     7
8   ISNB*     8
9    ISB*     9
10  ISNB*    10
> myDF.nb <- myDF[grepl("ISNB*", myDF$Source), ]
> print(myDF.nb)
   Source Value
2   ISNB*     2
4   ISNB*     4
6   ISNB*     6
8   ISNB*     8
10  ISNB*    10
```

When I make the subset of myDF to create myDF.b, I use `grepl("ISB*", myDF$Source), ]`. Now, what I'd expect would be that it grabs only the `ISB*` rows, but it grabs all of them. I realize that `ISNB*` contains all the same letters in the same order as `ISB*`, but I was surprised to see that the `N` in between didn't throw off `grepl` from matching it. I'd expect `ISB*N` to match with `ISB*`, but not with the `N` in the middle.

Is this normal behavior or is there an argument I am missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to escape `*` as it is a special character which means zero or more.

```
myDF[grepl("ISB\\*", myDF$Source), ]
```

Or as @Pierre Lafortune mentioned, `fixed=TRUE` can be used (which would be faster)

```
myDF[grepl("ISB*", myDF$Source, fixed=TRUE), ]
```

Comment: Damn, that was obvious. I feel dumb now. Thanks!

Comment: It works `myDF[grepl("ISB*", myDF$Source, fixed=TRUE), ]`

Comment: @PierreLafortune  Yes, you are right, I was thinking something else while I checked.